# Get first element of array as array?

Tags: php

From this array:

```
array(3) { 
    ["news_status"]=> string(1) "1" 
    ["news_input_title"]=> string(10) "test title" 
    ["news_input_description"]=> string(61) "<p>test description over 20 symbols<br></p>" 
}
```

I want to get

```
["news_status"]=> string(1) "1"
```

but to look exactly same (to be array(1)), something like this :

```
array(1) { 
    ["news_status"]=> string(1) "1" 
}
```

most functions like reset, current get only value ..

Comment: `foreach($array as $key=>$value)`

Comment: But i want only first element, like array..

Comment: foreach ($this->request->post as $key => $value){
                $ss[$key] = $value;
                break;
            } 
i try with this but it's not very good, i think

Comment: `$result = array_slice($array, 0, 1, true);` This is a pretty strange thing to want to do though - if you always want the first element, then you must know which key it is, or it wouldn't be any use.

Comment: Yeah, that's it, THANK U !

Answer (score 2):

Try `$first_element = array_slice( $myArray , 0 , 1 )`